# Pipe to a script then reset stdin

Tags: zsh, stdin

I have a function I want to pipe values into:

```
function fn() }
  declare -a vals
  while IFS= read line; do
    vals+="$line"
  done

  some_build_tool "$vals[@]"
}
```

Above is a simplified example. I'm also adding function args to the vals array and a couple other things.

I call the fn like so

```
cat file.txt | fn
```

The problem is `some_build_tool` prompts the user for information. When I pipe to the fn the build tool skips through the user prompts. How do I read the piped in data as above but also change the build tool to receive from stdin? I have tried the following:

```
some_build_script "$vals[@]" < /dev/tty
```

By then I get a message that tty input is suspended.